# Count rows by grouping and reset counter on new group with datatable and R

Tags: r, group-by, count, data.table

I need to count the number of rows per data pool that a datatable gets. These require that the week column "week" and "Exist" must be filled in.
I have the following data:

```
week_2020 <- seq(202001, 202015, 1)
week_2021 <- seq(202101, 202110, 1)

Exist <- c("TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE",
           NA,NA,NA,
           "TRUE","TRUE",NA,NA,"TRUE","TRUE","TRUE","TRUE",
           NA,NA,NA,
           "TRUE",NA, NA)

Year <- c(rep(2020,15),rep(2021,10) )

df<-data.table(Store = "store_1", Client = "client_1", 
               Year = Year,
               week = c(week_2020, week_2021),
               Exist = Exist)
```

| Store | Client | Year | Week | Exist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202001 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202002 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202003 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202004 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202005 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202006 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202007 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202008 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202009 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202010 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202011 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202012 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202013 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202014 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202015 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202101 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202102 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202103 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202104 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202105 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202106 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202107 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202108 | TRUE |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202109 | NA |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202110 | NA |

As shown in the table, some data in the "Exist" column is NA, which means that it does not exist, but that grouping should be counted as well.

I have created a variable that helps me to count the weeks until I find the lost weeks, and then I should count them and reset the counter, and another that does the max count "n_week_Count" but I can't do what I need. I hope you can help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advice

This is what i have...

```
df[, ':=' (n_weekCount = 1:.SD[,(.N)] ), keyby = c("Store", "Client", "Year", "Exist")
   ][, ':=' (MaxweekCount = .SD[, max(n_weekCount)]), keyby = c("Store", "Client", "Year", "Exist")
][order(week)]
```

| Store | Client | Year | Week | Exist | n_weekCount | maxWeek_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202001 | TRUE | 1 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202002 | TRUE | 2 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202003 | TRUE | 3 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202004 | TRUE | 4 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202005 | TRUE | 5 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202006 | TRUE | 6 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202007 | TRUE | 7 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202008 | TRUE | 8 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202009 | NA | 1 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202010 | NA | 2 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202011 | NA | 3 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202012 | TRUE | 9 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202013 | TRUE | 10 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202014 | NA | 4 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202015 | NA | 5 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202101 | TRUE | 1 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202102 | TRUE | 2 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202103 | TRUE | 3 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202104 | TRUE | 4 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202105 | NA | 1 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202106 | NA | 2 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202107 | NA | 3 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202108 | TRUE | 1 | 10 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202109 | NA | 4 | 5 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202110 | NA | 5 | 5 |

The desired result would be:

| Store | Client | Year | Week | Exist | n_weekCount | maxWeek_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202001 | TRUE | 1 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202002 | TRUE | 2 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202003 | TRUE | 3 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202004 | TRUE | 4 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202005 | TRUE | 5 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202006 | TRUE | 6 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202007 | TRUE | 7 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202008 | TRUE | 8 | 8 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202009 | NA | 1 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202010 | NA | 2 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202011 | NA | 3 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202012 | TRUE | 1 | 2 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202013 | TRUE | 2 | 2 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202014 | NA | 1 | 2 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2020 | 202015 | NA | 2 | 2 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202101 | TRUE | 1 | 4 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202102 | TRUE | 2 | 4 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202103 | TRUE | 3 | 4 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202104 | TRUE | 4 | 4 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202105 | NA | 1 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202106 | NA | 2 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202107 | NA | 3 | 3 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202108 | TRUE | 1 | 1 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202109 | NA | 1 | 2 |
| Store 1 | Client 1 | 2021 | 202110 | NA | 2 | 2 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `rleid` for grouping and create the columns (`:=`) with `seq_len(.N)` and group size (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
df[, c("n_WeekCount", "maxWeek_Count") := .(seq_len(.N), .N),
      .(grp = rleid(Exist), Store, Client, Year)]
```

-output

```
> df
      Store   Client  Year   week  Exist n_WeekCount maxWeek_Count
     <char>   <char> <num>  <num> <char>       <int>         <int>
 1: store_1 client_1  2020 202001   TRUE           1             8
 2: store_1 client_1  2020 202002   TRUE           2             8
 3: store_1 client_1  2020 202003   TRUE           3             8
 4: store_1 client_1  2020 202004   TRUE           4             8
 5: store_1 client_1  2020 202005   TRUE           5             8
 6: store_1 client_1  2020 202006   TRUE           6             8
 7: store_1 client_1  2020 202007   TRUE           7             8
 8: store_1 client_1  2020 202008   TRUE           8             8
 9: store_1 client_1  2020 202009   <NA>           1             3
10: store_1 client_1  2020 202010   <NA>           2             3
11: store_1 client_1  2020 202011   <NA>           3             3
12: store_1 client_1  2020 202012   TRUE           1             2
13: store_1 client_1  2020 202013   TRUE           2             2
14: store_1 client_1  2020 202014   <NA>           1             2
15: store_1 client_1  2020 202015   <NA>           2             2
16: store_1 client_1  2021 202101   TRUE           1             4
17: store_1 client_1  2021 202102   TRUE           2             4
18: store_1 client_1  2021 202103   TRUE           3             4
19: store_1 client_1  2021 202104   TRUE           4             4
20: store_1 client_1  2021 202105   <NA>           1             3
21: store_1 client_1  2021 202106   <NA>           2             3
22: store_1 client_1  2021 202107   <NA>           3             3
23: store_1 client_1  2021 202108   TRUE           1             1
24: store_1 client_1  2021 202109   <NA>           1             2
25: store_1 client_1  2021 202110   <NA>           2             2
```

Comment: It works perfect! Thank you so much. I spend many hours trying to figure it out, and today, iIlearned something new. Thanks again!